# PHP get array object from a class

Tags: php

I have a page which creates an instance of a class. This class gets some information on the user (their badges) but when I return the object I only get the first record. Some code below.

```
$badges = new Badges;

$result = $badges->getBadges($userID);
$row_array[] = $result;
echo json_encode($row_array);


class Badges
{
    function getBadges($userID)
    {
        $get_badge_query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], "SELECT * FROM tbl_my_badges WHERE user_id = '" . $userID . "'");

        while($get_badge_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_badge_query)) {
            $result = array("done" => "true",
                            "badge_icon" => $get_badge_result['badge_icon'],
                            "badge_text" => $get_badge_result['badge_message']);

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding an array variable outside the loop and populating this with the results and returning the variable but still doesn't work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please explain what do you think `$result = array("done" => "true",...` line of code does.

Comment: Doesn't work means I still only get one result when I know there are more than that in the DB.

Comment: yep, I changed my comment. It's expected from your code :-) You don't store all the results but only the last one

Comment: What do you mean by "the first record", just 'badge_icon' or both 'badge_icon' and 'badge_message'? You are only `SELECT`ing one record, unless you have multiple people with the same `$userId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accumulate the results into an array, then return that:

```
$results = array();
while($get_badge_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_badge_query)) {
    $results[] = array("done" => "true",
                    "badge_icon" => $get_badge_result['badge_icon'],
                    "badge_text" => $get_badge_result['badge_message']);
}
return $results;
```

Otherwise you're just overwriting the `$result` variable on each iteration, and it will always be set to the last record in the DB.

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify it slightly, not sure why but when I returned $results and tried to assign it to another array $row_array it still didn't work. So basically I have $row_array[] = $result and seems to work.